# Chekhov story involving a "peeping tom" priest and a newly married couple?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, anton-chekhov

- The story takes place on a ship and involves the priest spying on the newlyweds couple in their cabin.

Can't remember the title though.  (It was re-published in one of his short story collections in English.)

Comment: I found ["Ariadne"](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Aria.shtml), a shortish story about a man on a ship talking to his cabin mate about his relationship with a woman. Doesn't quite match your description, but has some common elements. I guess there's no chance you misremembered that badly?

Comment: Also ["Gusev"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gusev_(short_story)), about a priest on a ship but no married couple.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I recall discussing it in a class I took on Chekhov's stories.  (The man wrote a lot of them!  Even the most extensive online lists I am not sure are complete. If I do come across it, I'll either self-answer or delete the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like *В море* ("On the sea"):

- There is a newlyweds' cabin on the ship in the sea
- The sailors have made two holes in the cabin walls to spy on the newlyweds for their own amusement
- The cabin is occupied by a newlywed Protestant priest and his wife, the sailors (a father and his son) are spying on them.
- They witness the pastor (who is apparently in need of money) convincing his young wife to prostitute herself to a rich English banker, to which she finally agrees. The pastor and his wife speak a language the sailors don't understand, so it's not clear what is the pastor convincing his wife of till the end of the story.
- When the sailors realize what's happening, the father stops watching in disgust and orders his son to do the same